# Merge multiple URL checks into one statement (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, href, window.location

Example:

```
    if (/entertainments/.test(window.location.href)) {
    //code here

}


       if (/suggestions/.test(window.location.href)) {
    //same code here

  }
```

I have tried

```
    if (/entertainments/||/suggestions/.test(window.location.href))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
if (/entertainments/.test(window.location.href) || /suggestions/.test(window.location.href)) {
    //code here
    console.log("Matches the req...");
}
```

As you're going to have one of them true, the if-body will be executed (in this case `console.log("Matches the req...");`)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly and makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(/entertainments/.test(window.location.href)||/suggestions/.test(window.location.href) )
```

Comment: Please explain what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to this

```
/^(entertainment|suggestion)/.test(window.location.href);
```